# return a single value in a dictionary with multiple values

Tags: python, python-requests

```
data = response.text

dict_data = json.loads(data)

k = dict_data.keys()
v = dict_data.values()

for k, v in dict_data.items():
    print(k, '->', v)
```

Is it possible to search for 'temp' and return just that value? I don't need any of the other info.
Output:

```
coord -> {'lon': -74.006, 'lat': 40.7143}
weather -> [{'id': 800, 'main': 'Clear', 'description': 'clear sky', 'icon': '01d'}]
base -> stations
main -> {'temp': 73.26, 'feels_like': 72.25, 'temp_min': 66.2, 'temp_max': 79, 'pressure': 1007, 'humidity': 42}
visibility -> 10000
wind -> {'speed': 8.05, 'deg': 250}
clouds -> {'all': 1}
dt -> 1619976931
sys -> {'type': 1, 'id': 4610, 'country': 'US', 'sunrise': 1619949178, 'sunset': 1619999569}
timezone -> -14400
id -> 5128581
name -> New York
cod -> 200
```

Comment: `dict_data["main"]["temp"]`?

Comment: You have redundant lines in your code (`k = ...`, `v = ...`) and in is not clear what the desired output is. Also, try to solve yourself before posting and include your attempt in the question.

Comment: Btw you can just use data = response.json() for cleaner code

Answer (score 0):

If would check with an if statement. Something like this:

```
data = response.text

dict_data = json.loads(data)

for item in dict_data:
    if 'temp' in item:
        print("temp", '->', dict_data[item]['temp'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://pypi.org/project/nested-lookup/) little package to be very useful when querying and operating on dictionaries.

To get all keys and values where key ~= "temp" you can do:

```
results = nested_lookup(
    key = "temp",
    document = dict_data,
    wild = True
)

print(results)
```

If you want key == "temp" just pass `wild=False`

You can also use this package for nested update of keys, get number of occurrences of keys and more.